# Selenium not able to get some data on the web page

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium with Python to get some data about Chrome extensions. I am trying to get the number of users of particular extension at [this page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/id-vault/jlljbiieciifehccmokcpnmlklpaimpa/details). I am using the code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException
import time  

def create_browser(first_page=None):
        print "Starting"
        browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/user/ChromeDriver/chromedriver')
        if first_page:
            browser.get(first_page);
        print "Done."
        return browser


    def wait_find_element_by_xpath(driver, path):
        counter = 0
        while counter < 7:
            try:
                elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
                break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                time.sleep(1)
                counter += 1
                elem = None
        return elem

    URL = 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/id-vault/jlljbiieciifehccmokcpnmlklpaimpa/details' 

    browser = create_browser()
    browser.get(URL)
    time.sleep(7) 
    #Get number of users
    userStr = wait_find_element_by_xpath(browser, './/span[@class="webstore-f-g-He"]')
    #print "\n\n\n No. of Users: "
    #print userStr
    #print userStr.text
    #print "\n\n\n-----"
    noOfUserStr = userStr.text.replace(" users", "")
    noOfUsers = noOfUserStr.replace(",", "")
    users = int(noOfUsers)
```

My problem is I am not able to get the number of users at *that* particular page. Instead I get the error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

I find this strange because the code works well with other extensions. Also, even when you click see the source (Right Click-> Inspect element) you see the number of users in the source (just after the "from" field) but I am still not able to get the value. Can anyone help me fix the problem?

Comment: Please provide working code. The imports are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for this particular extension, the number of users is not visible due to the length of the "from" url.  Selenium generally only works on visible elements in the document.

I would recommend getting this value via javascript execution:

```
userStr = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('webstore-f-g-He')[0].textContent")
```